# Errors when using dot2texi in MikTeX

Tags: miktex, graphs

I receive errors in log file while trying to compile the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{dot2texi}

\begin{document}
  \begin{dot2tex}[neato,options=-tmath]
    digraph G {
      node [shape="circle"];
      a_1 -> a_2 -> a_3 -> a_4 -> a_1;
 }
\end{dot2tex}
\end{document}
```

It is an example from dot2tex website. An example of the error is:

```
Undefined control sequence \begin{dot2tex}[neato,options=-tmath]
```

The author of the package suggests [on this link](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/dot2tex-users/kbjZGRVT5SY/GhK7WUGmO5YJ), that you should define

```
\@ifundefined{verbatim@out}{\newwrite\verbatim@out}{}%
```

inside your package, but I still cannot understand where should I put this command, because I am TeX-newbee.

FIX: I have put `\@ifundefined{verbatim@out}{\newwrite\verbatim@out}{}%` into `dot2texi.sty` right in the beginning:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1999/12/01]
\ProvidesPackage{dot2texi}[2008/05/07 v3.0 Run dot2tex from LaTeX]
\RequirePackage{moreverb}
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}[2005/02/22]

\@ifundefined{verbatim@out}{\newwrite\verbatim@out}{}% 

\newif\ifdtt@ShellEscape
%\newif\ifmiktex \miktexfalse
```

Comment: Modifying style files is usually not a good idea. I suppose that writing the line between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` just after `\usepackage{dot2texi}` would be good as well.

Comment: @egreg, I have done that because it was recommended by the author of `dot2tex(i)`. Thank you, your fix also works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifying style files is usually not a good idea. Writing the line between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` just after `\usepackage{dot2texi}` would be good as well:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{dot2texi}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{verbatim@out}{\newwrite\verbatim@out}{}
\makeatother
```